# Syslog Netty Server - Defaultdelimiter

Tags: netty, syslog

I am using Netty to set up a Syslog server but I am confused which delimiter I should take.

When I do not use any DelimiterFramers, then the syslog is cut off after the byte size.
How can I make sure that the Syslog message is complete. I know I should use the byte size and count the length of the message but the thing is when I am sending many messages at the same time, the byte sizes are received first and later on the rest of the message so that it is impossible for me to count the byte size of the message.

Now when I take Delimiter.lineDelimiter() the message is not passed to channelRead0 as there is no "\r\n" (Non-Transparent-Framing) at the end of the syslog message.

I need to ensure that I get the full syslog [byteSize syslogMessage]from the tcp socket

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the transport type, try to read this https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6587 3.4.  Message Transfer